# While showing notebook inside my website Iframe, It shows “Couldn’t authenticate WebSocket connection” and codes are not executed

Tags: iframe, websocket, jupyter-notebook, http-status-code-403

I was trying to integrate jupyter-notebook inside my web application through iframe. I was able to show the .ipynb file inside the iframe. But codes are not executing. It shows asterisks on the left side. (Without iframe, everything is working perfectly)
[image]

Here are the logs:

```
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:55.503 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:55.504 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 1.64ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:55.520 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:55.521 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 2.27ms referer=None
[I 2024-03-18 22:22:55.529 ServerApp] 302 GET /kernelspecs/python3/logo-64x64.png (@127.0.0.1) 0.81ms
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:56.167 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:56.167 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 0.97ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:58.663 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:22:58.663 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 0.94ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-18 22:23:00.387 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:23:00.388 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 1.48ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-18 22:23:11.907 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:23:11.908 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 1.00ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-18 22:23:35.230 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:23:35.231 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 0.95ms referer=None
[W 2024-03-18 22:24:32.856 ServerApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 2024-03-18 22:24:32.857 ServerApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/b7c10128-b9ca-41b7-be4e-d9306929beae/channels?session_id=54f772e9-d019-4325-a57e-5307e529a961 (@127.0.0.1) 1.49ms referer=None
```

Here is the jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c = get_config()
c.ServerApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.ServerApp.allow_remote_access = True
c.ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
c.ServerApp.tornado_settings = {'headers': {'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors self https://example.com/", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.com/"}, "cookie_options": {"SameSite": "None", "Secure": True}}
```